# Do looping through items and adding handlers to it hurt performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-events

Does it hurt in performance when I loop through list-items and add a click-handler to all separate items?

The reason I do this is because I would only like to make the list item clickable if it contains an hyperlink.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
$('ul.paginator li').each(function() {
  if ($('a', this).length > 0) {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $(this).click(function() {
      location.href = $('a', this).attr('href');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how much it might hurt performance, but have you considered using a somewhat simplified jQuery selector:

```
$('ul.paginator li:has(a)').each(
    function(){
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer').click(
            function(){
                location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
            });
    });
```

Incidentally, the performance would depend on the number of elements you're searching through more than anything else. Just a few and it's likely to be imperceptible, a few thousand and it will (probably) be noticeable.

---

**Edited** to reduce the expense of `has()`:

```
$('ul.paginator li a').each(
    function(){
        var address = this.href;
        $(this).closest('li').css('cursor','pointer').click(
            function(){
                location.href = address;
            });
    });
```

This should be less expensive, as it will select only those `a` elements within an `li`, and then move up to affect that `li` element.

Comment: `:has(a)` is computationally expensive

Comment: @David Thomas: great! didn't think about `has()`! Exactly what I was looking for. I even don't have a use anymore of the `each()`. I can now just do: `$('ul.paginator li:has(a)').click(function() {}).css();`

Comment: @Raynos: owh :( How bad is it?

Comment: @Raynos, it is; but more so than running an `if` statement on every element returned by the selector?

Comment: @DavidThomas yes it is. it's better to do it manually then in the selector, unless its a proper selector and not a fake jquery one

Comment: @Raynos, thanks for the heads-up! Hopefully the edited version should be slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is better to use `delegate` with a proper selector that selects only the items you want.

There will be only one handler created and attached.

If you don't want to use `has()` than this will be enough (no need for multiple handlers):

```
$('ul.paginator').delegate('click', 'li', function() {
    var link = $('a', this);
    if (link.length > 0) {
        location.href = link.attr('href');
    }
});
```

Comment: But the thing is: there is no proper selector for this. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: Updated the answer if you don't want to use `has`

Comment: I would add a css class (ie. 'clickable') to each `li` with `a` as I render them (that would solve many problems). With current approach I would do `$('ul.paginator').find('a').closest('li').css('cursor', 'pointer')`

Answer (score 0):

depends how many rows there are.  If there are thousands of them, then yes.  If there are a modest amount then not really enough to be noticeable.

An alternative approach would be to put the click handler on the element that contains the items, and then when a click event comes in, to use the data in the event passed to the handler to determine what to do.  One handler.